# How to add comments in a .json file

Tags: javascript, json, comments

Consider:

```
{
    "one": {
        "one1":"one11",
        "System Name":"ssss"
    },
    "two2": [
        ["two20", "two200"]
    ]
}
```

If I use '/* comments */' or //comments, I can not get JSON data.

But I have too much data, and I must add comments.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Json strings are a data format used to simplify parsing, if you want to display nicely datas use a database or something

Comment: As you can see from the link posted by Vicky, you cannot have comments in JSON files as it will be interpreted as data. There are some workarounds if you really, really need them, like defining a data element which is dummy, igonred and used only for commenting purposes

Answer (score 3):

*No*, comments are not part of the [JSON RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159). However, there are JSON parsers which support C++-Style comments:

```
{
  "img":{ "width": 320, "height": 240 } // Picture details
}
```

See [JSON++](https://github.com/hjiang/jsonxx).

So the answer depends on what you are going to do with your JSON. The JavaScript-JSON parser (`JSON.parse()`) doesn't support this.